# How to upload to a few tables in bigquery using gcloud

Tags: node.js, google-bigquery, gcloud

Is there a way to upload different data to a few tables in one load job to bigquery using nodejs gcloud library or using bq command line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. It's one load job per table.

https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/loading-data

If you're feeling adventurous, you could write a Dataflow pipeline which reads from multiple sources and writes to multiple sinks in BigQuery.

https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/model/bigquery-io